# Recreating iPhone stock application with nested views

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am trying to create an app similar to the Yahoo Stocks app that comes on the iPhone, with the split-screen interface (table on the top, graph on the bottom).  I'm struggling with the view hierarchy.

What is the easiest way to implement a split-screen type of application.  I basically want two views nested in a parent view.  My problem is a little bit more complex because I want functionality like having a uipagecontrol (does this require another viewcontroller, or is simply implemented in the initial view controller)?

To what degree do I need to use IB?  I would prefer to do this all in Xcode.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a question, not a criticism  - why would you prefer to do this all in XCode and not use Interface Builder?  I see a lot of people with this and want to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't create the views and put them inside of any other kind of `UIView` you want, particularly `UIScrollView`. Simply arrange their frames to be in the right position.